# Replica de un texto

Tags: php

Este es mi código, simplemente quiero replicar ese pequeño texto  a través de un bucle for.

el resultado que me da es, Holaolalaa no entiendo por que me sale así.

```
<?php

$text = "Hola";
$length = strlen($text);

for($i=0;$i<=$length;$i++){

    $rest = substr($text, $i);

   echo $rest;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar también [**`str_split`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php), que te crea un array con los caracteres de tu cadena. Luego puedes pasar a leer ese array caracter por caracter.

Por ejemplo:

```
$text = "Hola";
$textParts=str_split($text);
foreach ($textParts as $char) {
    echo $char.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
H
o
l
a
```

Answer (score 2):

Te sale así por el indice del bucle. Lo que estas haciendo es que te coga el texto al principio como el indice es 0 te imprime la palabra entera y después te va quitando un caracter de la variable $text.

```
$text = "Hola"; //texto
$length = strlen($text); //numero de caracters que tiene el texto

for($i=0;$i<=$length;$i++){
  $rest = substr($text, $i); //cogeme el numero de caracters del texto segun i

  echo $rest; //imprime el texto
}
```

Si quieres que la palabra tiene 4 caracters y que se repita 4 veces tienes que hacer:

```
$text = "Hola";
$length = strlen($text);

for($i=0;$i<=$length;$i++){
   echo $text;
}
```

Si quieres imprimir caracter a caracter haz lo siguiente en el bucle:

```
for($i=0;$i<=$length;$i++){ 
   echo $text[$i]; //imprime el caracter que toca. 
}
```

Comment: Y que indice debería poner para que sólo me sale una vez?

yo pensaba que iba i[0]=h, i[1]=O etc..

Es que lo que quiero es en el futuro poder analizar otros tipos de textos con espacios,